# Oracle Number cast to .Net decimal

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I am mapping an Entity Framework project to an existing Oracle database.  I have a class:

```
public class Order 
{
   [Key]
   public string OrderNo {get;set;} // Oracle type VARCHAR2(100)
   public decimal Cost {get;set;} // Oracle type NUMBER (no precision)
}

public DbSet<Order> Orders {get;set;}
```

Then executing the following:

```
context.Orders.Find("0001");
```

returns the error `Specified cast is not valid!`.  This looks like its caused by a very large decimal value in the COST column.  I have tried setting the following attribute on the entity:

```
[Column("ROUND(COST,2)"]
public decimal Cost {get;set;}
```

Which causes an exception with the generated SQL `OracleException: ORA-00904: "Extent1"."ROUND(COST,2)": invalid identifier`.  I would like it to generate `ROUND("Extent1".COST,2)`.

Is there a way to force the database to convert the column as part of the SQL statement?